# TypeScript: Function interface as a callable inside a class

Tags: typescript

I want to create an function interface, that can act as a callable inside a class.

So basically what I want to do is the following:

```
interface Callable {
    (x: number): number;
    someAdditionalStuff?: any;
}

class Foo {
    doSomething: Callable (x: number) {
        return x + 3;
    }
}
```

I know that `Foo.doSomething` hasn't the correct syntax.

I wondered if this is somehow possible to achieve?

**Update:** To make it little bit more clear. What I want is, that the type of `doSomehting` is `Callable`. But I want to flesh out the function body in the class, not in the interface and I don't want that you have to set `someAdditionalStuff` anywhere in the class or function implementation.

The target is, that I can add stuff to the class member, that are different, each time I create a new instance of the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write this:

```
interface Callable {
    (x: number): number;
    someAdditionalStuff?: any;
}

class Foo {
    doSomething: Callable = (x: number) => {
        return x + 3;
    }
}
```

One important question is what you want the semantics of `Foo.doSomething.someAdditionalStuff` to be. With the above code, each instance of `Foo` gets its own copy of the `doSomething` closure, so changes in one class are not reflected in the other:

```
var x = new Foo();
var y = new Foo();
x.doSomething.someAdditionalStuff = 3;
// Changing this value does not change the value on 'x' - desired?
y.doSomething.someAdditionalStuff = 'foo';
```

I would guess this is what you want.

If you want `someAdditionalStuff` to essentially be 'static', there's a more complicated workaround that you could do. I'll try to come up with something simpler...

```
class _Bar {
    someOtherThing() {}
    doSomething(x: number) {
        return x + 3;
    }
}

interface Bar extends _Bar {
    doSomething: Callable;
}

var Bar: { new(): Bar } = _Bar;

// User code:
var f = new Bar();
var g = new Bar();
f.doSomething.someAdditionalStuff = 'ok';
alert(g.doSomething.someAdditionalStuff); // "ok"
```

Comment: No, I don't want it to be static. But your first solution is the exact thing I was looking for. Thank you very much.